# Looking for suggestions on how to send Paypal Meta Client ID of a user which is triggered from a different device. (Uber like behavior)

Tags: ios, paypal, payment

I've implemented Future Payment in my iOS app. Now the problem is I have to send the metaclientid to the server in order to make the payment however the trigger of "its time to charge paypal" is on a different device. Think of the app like uber wherein the passenger only gets charged when they arrived on their destination. And "arrived" is triggered from the driver app.

There are ways I'm thinking on how to go with it

1. Through push notif. I'll send a push -> catch it -> send metaClientID 
   (Issue: Probably unreliable since push can fail and user can go offline and not receive the push at all)
2. Store the MetaClientID to the server (As per paypal storing this is not recommended)

Would appreciate your feedback or suggestions.